# PHP openssl_decrypt() breakes completely within a for loop

Tags: php, openssl

I wrote a basic php script to store simple strings in an encrypted way using a CSV table.

If I directly encrypt and decript the strings, the final output perfectly matches the input.

However using a for loop of the explode(";;:;;;",$csv_string); breaks in an absolutely crazy way. The error should be absolutely obvious to find. I am using the function openssl_decrypt in mode "aes-256-gcm".

First, what works perfectly fine:

```
working_for_loop(blah)
{
   $password="pw_test";
   $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length("aes-128-gcm");
   $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
   $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($ticket_content,"aes-256-gcm", $password, $options=0, $iv, $tag);

   echo $encrypted."<br>".$iv."<br>";

   echo openssl_decrypt($encrypted,"aes-256-gcm", $password, $options=0, $iv, $tag)."<br>";
   $csv_entry.=$encrypted.";;:;;;".$iv.";;:;;;";
}
```

This works perfect. The entries are added to the line, that than gets written to the CSV. Currently I am skipping the step, to write to the csv. I am directly using $csv_entry in the script again later.

INPUT: (That is a PHP POST request and I just show, what I enter to the fields)

```
Action: Set server on fire
IP ADDRESS: 0815.152.256.-1
MAC Address: 12:34:56:78:90:12
```

OUTPUT:

```
LUDzwGB8iWBGB2zLsCIMtybA
ö�cI�S��h{
Set server on fire
9skXTW074UhpeWheGyqj
]_��<8�jeU
0815.152.256.-1
zWygdB9yud9TPxOd8NumyO4=
�8rt��.�=�ڥ
12:34:56:78:90:12
```

The first from the output is the encrypted message, the 2nd is the $iv (initial vector) and the 3rd is the successfully decrypted message

Now watch, what happens, when I want to decrypt the same data from a CSRV line:

INPUT:

```
LUDzwGB8iWBGB2zLsCIMtybA;;:;;;ö�cI�S��h{;;:;;;9skXTW074UhpeWheGyqj;;:;;;]_��<8�jeU;;:;;;zWygdB9yud9TPxOd8NumyO4=�8rt��.�=�ڥ;;:;;;
```

CODE:

```
$read_csrv=explode(";;:;;;",$csv_entry);

for($i=0;$i<count($read_csrv)-2;$i+=2)
{
   echo "Test <br>".$read_csrv[$i]."<br>".$read_csrv[$i+1]."<br>";
   echo openssl_decrypt($read_csrv[$i],"aes-256-gcm", $password, $options=0, $read_csrv[$i+1], $tag)."<br>";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
TEST
LUDzwGB8iWBGB2zLsCIMtybA
ö�cI�S��h{

TEST
9skXTW074UhpeWheGyqj
]_��<8�jeU

TEST
zWygdB9yud9TPxOd8NumyO4=
�8rt��.�=�ڥ
12:34:56:78:90:12
```

That is really strange. It only decrypts the last message.

I thought it is obvious: The decryption did not work, because $iv was set to the last entry from the list and I forgot that, but that is not actually the case. IV is set correctly as: $read_csrv[$i+1]

Also the debugging output clearly shows, that $iv is changing in the for loop as expected. It actually behaves a bit, as if this value gets pre-calculated and than the for loop actually runs the decryption, which only works on the last entry. Did I miss anything absolutely obvious? It behaves just a bit like in Windows Batch without "delayedexpansion" enabled.

I used ;;:;;; to be 100% safe, that this is an actual delimiter. The issue is, that basically anything can be the encrypted code. This means, that a single ";" easily occours and breaks the math, resulting not in x*2, but x*2+1 entries or even more. ;;:;;; might be extremely overkill, but better safe than sorry, especially if the code does not work for some reason I do not grasp.

Please also note, that this does not even work with a fixed $iv value. The output shows the same $iv all the time, but still only the last entry gets decrypted. I also thorougly checked, that the csv line generation works as expected. What might it be?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You may possibly have better luck if you stored "bin2hex($iv)" into your CSV data instead of $iv directly. Then read it from the CSV and use "hex2bin($iv)" to get it back into a binary number for the decryption function. I say this because storing binary data in what is essentially intended to be a text file is rife with problems, including the possibility of including ASCII codes for comma, semi-colon, or the NULL string terminator. And since it's cryptographically random, it won't be easily repeatable.